# VSCode cannot Autoimport flutter_gen

Tags: flutter, dart, visual-studio-code

I'm following [this doc](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/accessibility-and-localization/internationalization) to implement localization in my app. I run `flutter build apk` and it generates related localization classes. However, when I want to import `AppLocalizations` under lib, it does not automatically import it. So I manually write `import 'package:flutter_gen/gen_l10n/app_localizations.dart';` to every file I'd like to use localization.

I was wondering if there's a way to make VSCode autoimport generated `AppLocalizations` class when I do `CTRL+.` since writing import each time is a pain.

## l10n.yaml file

```yaml
arb-dir: l10n
template-arb-file: app_tr.arb
output-localization-file: app_localizations.dart
```

---

## Environment

- VSCode 1.55.1
- [Ultimate Flutter Extension Pack](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=MarufHassan.flutter)

Comment: Faced a same issue. I'm Still manually adding the imports.

Comment: Having the same issue in Android Studio

Comment: Any solution yet?

Comment: @SamDoggett the answer seems to be one of the solution.

Answer (score 2):

Create a `app_localizations.dart` at your project `/lib`:

```dart
export 'package:flutter_gen/gen_l10n/app_localizations.dart'
    show AppLocalizations;
```

VSCode autoimport work!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I have taken another way to localize my Flutter app. In Visual Studio Code, I have installed this plugin, Flutter Intl (localizely.flutter-intl) and I have followed the plugin instructions.
In this scenario, the LocalizationDelegate file, is built inside /lib folder.

In this way, the auto-import works fine. Futhermore with this plugin, I can use ICU format messages like select, plural, etc in easy way.